# String checking Python

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a string representing a filename, how can I check it against few conditions at once? I've tried

```
if r'.jpg' or r'.png' not in singlefile:
```

but kept getting false positives all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is equal with:

```
if (r'.jpg') or (r'.png' not in singlefile):
```

You're, probably, looking for:

```
if r'.jpg' not in singlefile or r'.png' not in singlefile:
```

Or

```
if any(part not in singlefile for part in [r'.jpg', r'.png']):
```

---

Thanks to Tim Pietzcker:

> He(you) actually (probably) wants
>
> ```
> if not any(singlefile.endswith(part) for part in [r'.jpg', r'.png'])
> #                     ^^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: Right. And he *actually* (probably) wants `if not any(singlefile.endswith(part) for part in [r'.jpg', r'.png'])`.

Comment: Yeah using `endswith` is probably the best solution

Answer (score 2):

This is because of precedence. Following code means.

```
# r'.jpg' is constant
if r'.jpg' or (r'.png' not in singlefile):
```

If constant, or `.png` not in `singlefile`. As constant is always true, the expression is always truthy.

Instead, you could try using regular expressions, to check whatever string fits a pattern.

```
import re
if re.match(r"\.(?:jpg|png)$", singlefile):
```

Comment: I'd prefer regex for check too, but you was faster. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is with the fact that your logical OR is checking a constant and a variable.

```
r'.png'
```

will always evaluate to True, thus making your `or` true as well.

you have to check for both, like so

```
if r'.png' not in singlefile or 'r.jpg'  not in singlefile:
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if r'.jpg' not in singlefile or r'.png' not in singlefile:
```